# In Chromium webdriver, the web activies not running

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Can you tell why this code is failing? this code is working when I change this url to another url (to my own website), but for this site (mithuri.appzila.lk), it is not working, if it work, it should returned the page title as "නම්බර්ස්" but it's not. If you know the solution, we would really appreciate it by letting us know, because we're trying to down a scam site.

this is the code part:

```
count = 1
i = 1

while i <= count:

  _number = random_number()

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  # chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

  browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

  try:
      browser.get("https://www.mithuri.appzila.lk/")
      time.sleep(0.11)
      # with open("results.txt", "w") as f:
      #     f.write("Page title was: {}".format(browser.title))
      print("*")
      print("*")
      print("Page title was '{}'".format(browser.title))

      number = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#wpforms-6-field_2')
      submit = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'wpforms-submit-6')

      time.sleep(0.11)
      number.send_keys(_number)

      time.sleep(0.11)
      browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)

      # after click submit, check for verify
      time.sleep(5)

      title = format(browser.title)
      if title == "නම්බර්ස්":
        status = "SUCCESS"
      else :
        status = "FAILED"

  except Exception as e:
      # with open("results.txt", "w") as f:
      #     f.write(f"Failed to make the request {e} /n")
      print(f"Error occurred while running => {e}")

  finally:
      browser.quit()

  print(f"{i} Attempt {status} with number: {_number}")
  i += 1
  time.sleep(1)
```

this is the output:

> Page title was 'කෙල්ලෙක් සෙට් කරගන්න – ලංකාවෙ අංක එකේ මිතුරු සේවය'

> 1 Attempt FAILED with number: 07xxxxxxxx